# Alternatives to executing a script using cron job every second?

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I have a radio station at Tunein.com. In order to update album art and artist information, I need to send the following

```
  # Update the song now playing on a station
    GET http://air.radiotime.com/Playing.ashx?partnerId=<id>&partnerKey=<key>&id=<stationid>&title=Bad+Romance&artist=Lady+Gaga
```

The only way I can think to do this would be by setting up a PHP/JS page that updates the &title and &artist part of the URL and sends it off if there is a change. But I'd have to execute it every second, or at least every few seconds, using cron.

Are there any other more efficient ways this could be done?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have to check it on regular interval of time then CRON is the best way to go for it

Comment: Can you better describe exactly from where you are pulling the album and artist information? There are two approaches: 1. Have a program monitor something that will change and act when it does (which seems to be what you're doing) or 2. Have the process that makes the change also trigger the update. Generally speaking 2 will be more efficient but not necessarily to a significant degree. Again, more details on your setup are necessary for any advice.

Comment: The problem with Cron is that AFAIK, the minimum interval is 1 minute - and even if it could do 1s, it runs regardless of whether or not the previous execution has stopped or not. Perhaps you could daemonise and automate your script using the Fat Controller: http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net   There's a fitting example use-case described here: http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/use-cases.html#processing-events

Comment: @TomDworzanski - The original broadcast is streamed from Radionomy.com. Radionomy allow the title and artist information to be retrieved from their API. The information is retrieved as an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

**None of the code in this answer was tested. Use at your own risk.**

Since you do not control the third-party API and the API is not capable of pushing information to you when it's available (an ideal situation), your only option is to poll the API at some interval to look for changes and to make updates as necessary. *(Be sure the API provider is okay with such an approach as it might violate terms of use designed to prevent system abuse.)*

You need some sort of long-running process that will execute at a given interval.

You mentioned cron calling a PHP script which is one option (here cron is the long-running process). Cron is very stable and would be a good choice. I believe though that cron has a minimum interval of 1 minute. I'm sure there are similar tools out there, but those might require you to have full control over your server.

You could also make a PHP script the long-running process with something like this:

```
while(true){
    doUpdates();  # Call the API, make updates, etc
    sleep(5);     # Wait 5 seconds
}
```

If you do go down the PHP route, error handling of some sort will be a must:

```
while(true){
    try{
        doUpdates();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        # manage the error
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

---

***Personal Advice***

Using PHP as a daemon is possible but it is not as well tested as the typical use of PHP. If this task was given to me, I'd write a server/application in JavaScript using Node.js. I would prefer Node because it is designed to work as a long running process and intervals/events are a key part of JavaScript and I would be more confident in that working well than PHP for this specific task.

Comment: While you're right about the approach, the part where php leaks memory is absolute bullshit, excuse my french. It's your personal opinion and absolutely incorrect. One can freely use PHP for daemons, the problem is that PHP programmers use PHP for web development where lifecycle is request-reply and then PHP cleans the mess automatically, which isn't so with daemons and CLI where programmers should clean their own mess on their own. I won't downvote you, but please don't spread misinformation without actual proof that can be replicated (which hasn't been provided).

Comment: @N.B. Your explanation is exactly what I was getting it. I have no proof that PHP does or will leak memory.

Comment: Upvoted. On a side note, NodeJS uses an event loop. Same principle is available to PHP through an extension, making a PHP script neat and easy to understand. Given the actual problem OP has, I think event loop might be an overkill, so I'm giving you a +1.